# How can i navigate to mainviewcontroller from subview

Tags: uiview, swift, ios8, xcode6, subview

I have just started working with swift, i have created a subview which has a button on it, i would like to use that button to take me to my mainviewcontroller.

i have used same functionality for a different button however having a function in same file allows that button to work the code is below

```
var playAgainButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 150, 320, 40))
            playAgainButton.setTitle("Play Again", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            playAgainButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("startGame"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            playAgainButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            gameOver.addSubview(playAgainButton)
```

is it possible to use similar code to navigate to a different viewcontroller?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using storyboards, or is this all in code? If it's in code, create a method like

```
func goToMainVC() {
    if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

and set the button's target to a selector that calls it.

If you're using storyboards, you have three options:

1. ctrl+drag a connection from your button back to the main view controller (easy, but bad form because it just pushes the main VC back onto the nav controller);
2. Add `@IBAction` before the `fun goToMainVC()` method above, then ctrl+drag a connection from your button to the view controller in which it's contained, and then select that outlet method (this is how most people would do it); or
3. The best option is to use an unwind segue, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them).

Comment: its all in a code, i have just tried the goTo function, but when i click on home it doesnt do anything.

Comment: Hi Sorry i have now solved the issue, it was me who wasnt looking at the storyboard, i had to add a navigation controller, i did po self.navController anf found it was passing nil so went in the storyboard added a navigation controller and it started working. For fast response NRitH