# Switching Back & Forth Between View Controllers Swift

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

I don't know why but I'm having so much trouble trying to figure out how to go back to the main view. I use the code below to switch to the new view but how do I go back?

```
@IBAction func printPage(sender: AnyObject) {
        var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("labelView") as PrintLabelView
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        vc.toPass = skuLabel.text
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried, vc.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true , completion: nil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are presenting a UIViewController you should have some back button in the presented UIViewController by clicking it user is able to go back.

In the IBAction of that button you could have following code:

```
@IBAction func goBack() {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
}
```

If you are using navigation view controller the functionality by default is provided by it.

Comment: This did it. Thank you! I remember using this back then but I thought for some reason it didn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Use Unwind.

In MainViewController

```
@IBAction unwindSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: UIStoryboardSegue){//any code you want executed upon return to mainVC
}
```

In NewViewController

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){//pass any information from New to Main here
}
```

Then, in NewVC, simply control+drag from whichever UIButton you want to cause the unwind to NewVC's `Exit` symbol and select `unwindSegue`

*

*

NOTE: Also if you want the unwind to happen programmatically instead of from a Button. 
[image]
Control+drag from NewVC yellow to exit, this will create an unwind segue under "Exit"[image] Select this "Unwind segue" and in attributes inspector give it an identifier.[image]

Now in NewVC create a function

```
func NameYourFunc(){performSegueWithIdentifier("TheIdentiferYouUsed", sender: self)}
```

and anywhere in your NewVC code when you want to perform this unwind simply call `NameYourFunc()`

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue before where i found it difficult to go back, 1st thing which i didnt have was navigation controller and required the below code

```
func goToMainVC() {
    if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

Please look at the answer which was posted when i had similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25922738/4056108)

Hope fully this will help