# correct initialization navigation controller swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, initialization

I have a *viewcontroller*, i named it as `SelectionPopUpViewController`. I embed that controller on a `UINavigationController`.

[image: controller picture]

From `SelectionPopUpViewController.swift`, I put:

```
@IBAction func okTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    let homeVc = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as HomeViewController
    self.navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVc)
    self.window?.rootViewController = self.navController
    //self.navController.pushViewController(homeVc, animated: true)
}
```

on above I put :

```
weak var window : UIWindow?
var navController : UINavigationController!
```

What I want is when user click that `okTapped` button, it will go to `HomeViewController`. I try to initialize like that but it did not work. Maybe my initialization wrong.

*What is the correct code to made that button work (go to `HomeViewController`)?*

Comment: If you want to go back to main screen again please have a look at the question i asked few months ago, this may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/25922738/4056108

Comment: tried with navController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true), it give nil and it did not go to HomeViewController.

Comment: Is your navigation controller set as root controller?

Comment: like this: self.navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVc) ?

Comment: HomeViewController and SelectionPopUpViewController are different navigation controller, but in the same storyboard.